# How does the scale of a cataclysm determine if we can look beyond it?

Tags: cosmology, time, big-bang

The textbook I am referring to (Physics for Scientists and Engineers ($9e$), page $1 469$, section $46.11$), has the following paragraph regading the Big Bang:

> ... This theory of cosmology states that the Universe had a beginning, **and furthermore that the beginning was so cataclysmic that it is impossible to look back beyond it**. According to this theory, the Universe erupted from an infinitely dense singularity about 14 billion years ago. The first few moments after the big bang saw such extremely high energy that it is beleived that all four interactions of physics were unified and all matter was contained within a quark-gluon plasma ...

I don't understand the statement in bold. How does the fact that the event was so cataclysmic prevent us from looking back further beyond it? Is it just that spacetime cannot be defined before this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cataclysmicity is not a physically measurable observable. That part of the quote is not physics. The first sentence should refer to the theories of cosmology, plural possessive.  Cosmology is a branch of physics encompassing many theories, observations, hypotheses, and models... not a theory itself. The theory that predicts a primordial singularity is General Relativity. GR is an almost perfectly successful theory, but most cosmologists suspect that the singularity prediction indicates a limitation of the usefulness of GR for modeling extreme density states, not a true fact about the history of the universe. The last sentence is true.

Comment: `but most cosmologists suspect that the singularity prediction indicates a limitation of the usefulness of GR for modeling extreme density states, not a true fact about the history of the universe.`

Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @AVS Two main reasons. Mostly because we don't have a properly working theory that unifies quantum mechanics and gravity. If we have a regime in which quantum effects and gravitational effects should both be significant, we have to use cobbled together mix-and-match models and can only approximate, not reliably predict. Second, a singularity predicts infinity as the measured value of certain observable, and experience from other theories e.g. classical Electromagnetism, is that infinity generating conditions represent nonphysical arrangements of matter.

Comment: Metaphor: If physics is a map, infinities are places on the map marked "here be dragons".